# Autowire a Set defined as <util:set> in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I trying to have `Set<LocationResolver>` defined in a Spring context like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.foo"/>

    <!-- Artifact LocationResolvers -->
    <bean id="fsLocationResolver" class="org.foo.storage.resolvers.FSLocationResolver" />
    <bean id="memoryLocationResolver" class="org.foo.storage.resolvers.InMemoryLocationResolver" />

    <!-- The Set<LocationResolver> -->
    <util:set id="resolvers" value-type="org.foo.storage.resolvers.LocationResolver">
        <ref bean="memoryLocationResolver"/>
        <ref bean="fsLocationResolver"/>
    </util:set>

    <bean id="configurationManager"
          class="org.foo.configuration.ConfigurationManager"
          init-method="init">
    </bean>

    <bean id="artifactResolutionService" class="org.foo.resolvers.ArtifactResolutionService">
        <property name="resolvers" ref="resolvers"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My `ArtifactResolutionService`:

```
package org.foo.storage.resolvers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ArtifactResolutionService
{

    @Resource(name = "resolvers")
    private Set<LocationResolver> resolvers;


    public Set<LocationResolver> getResolvers()
    {
        return resolvers;
    }

    public void setResolvers(Set<LocationResolver> resolvers)
    {
        this.resolvers = resolvers;
    }

}
```

My `ConfigurationManager` class:

```
package org.foo.configuration;

import org.foo.resource.ConfigurationResourceResolver;
import org.foo.storage.Storage;
import org.foo.storage.resolvers.ArtifactResolutionService;
import org.foo.storage.resolvers.LocationResolver;
import org.foo.xml.parsers.ConfigurationParser;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope ("singleton")
public class ConfigurationManager
{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigurationManager.class);

    private String configurationPath;

    private Configuration configuration;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationResourceResolver configurationResourceResolver;

    @Autowired
    private ArtifactResolutionService artifactResolutionService;


    public ConfigurationManager()
    {
    }

    public void init()
            throws IOException
    {
        Resource resource = configurationResourceResolver.getConfigurationResource("etc/configuration.xml",
                                                                                   "repository.config.xml",
                                                                                   "etc/configuration.xml");

        logger.info("Loading configuration from " + resource.toString() + "...");

        ConfigurationParser parser = new ConfigurationParser();

        configuration = parser.parse(resource.getInputStream());
        configuration.setResource(resource);

        dump();
    }

    public void dump()
    {
        System.out.println("Configuration version: " + configuration.getVersion());
        System.out.println("Listening on port: " + configuration.getPort());

        System.out.println("Loading storages...");
        for (String storageKey : configuration.getStorages().keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(" -> Storage: " + storageKey);
            Storage storage = configuration.getStorages().get(storageKey);
            for (String repositoryKey : storage.getRepositories().keySet())
            {
                System.out.println("    -> Repository: " + repositoryKey);
            }
        }

        // 
        // This throws a NullPointerException, as the resolvers are null.
        // 
        System.out.println("Loading resolvers...");
        for (LocationResolver resolver : artifactResolutionService.getResolvers())
        {
            System.out.println(" -> " + resolver.getClass());
        }
    }

    public void storeConfiguration(Configuration configuration, String file)
            throws IOException
    {
        ConfigurationParser parser = new ConfigurationParser();
        parser.store(configuration, file);
    }

    public Configuration getConfiguration()
    {
        return configuration;
    }

    public void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public String getConfigurationPath()
    {
        return configurationPath;
    }

    public void setConfigurationPath(String configurationPath)
    {
        this.configurationPath = configurationPath;
    }

    public ArtifactResolutionService getArtifactResolutionService()
    {
        return artifactResolutionService;
    }

    public void setArtifactResolutionService(ArtifactResolutionService artifactResolutionService)
    {
        this.artifactResolutionService = artifactResolutionService;
    }

}
```

The `resolvers`, however, end up being `null` and I can't seem to be able to figure this out. Is there something obvious, which I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Where are you using the `ArtifactResolutionService`?

Comment: You have 2 instances of the `ArtifactResolutionService`. One detected by component scanning, the other is the one configured in XML. A tip `<context:annotation-config />` is already implied by the use of `<context:component-scan />`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Thanks for you answer! I have removed the `component-scan` and added the `@Resource`, as recommended but the `resolvers` are still `null`.

Comment: Where are you calling the `ConfigurationManager#init` method?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I wonder if the problem has anything to do with the `init-method`? When exactly is it invoked? Before the values for the fields have been autowired, or after?

Comment: @carlspring The stack trace says "Error creating bean with name 'artifactRestlet'" but that's not in the source code you posted above.

Comment: @carlspring Can you post the code to org.foo.storage.resolvers.FSLocationResolver? It looks like this is where it's dying: " Cannot resolve reference to bean 'fsLocationResolver' while setting bean property 'sourceSet' with key [1]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things should be warning sings.

First you have this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.foo"/>
```

with

```
package org.foo.storage.resolvers;

@Component
public class ArtifactResolutionService
```

which means your are **implicitly** creating a `ArtifactResolutionService` bean. You also have

```
<bean id="artifactResolutionService" class="org.foo.resolvers.ArtifactResolutionService">
    <property name="resolvers" ref="resolvers"/>
</bean>
```

which **explicitly** creating a second `ArtifactResolutionService` bean (the bean definitions might overwrite each other however because they would have the same id). In both cases, you have a way to inject the `Set` of resolvers. One with `@Autowired`, the other with `<property>`.

Second, it's impossible for your Spring configuration to inject `null` in a managed bean.

It's possible you are trying to use the field at a bad time during the lifecycle of the beans, where the field hasn't been injected yet.

So it seems you have a circular dependency. Spring tries to inject `ConfigurationManager` into one of the `LocationResolver` before it's autowired its fields. To do that, it needs to call the `init-method`.

---

Note that with annotation configuration, I believe this

```
@Autowired
private Set<LocationResolver> resolvers;
```

will actually pick up all the `LocationResolver` beans, not your `Set` bean defined here

```
<!-- The Set<LocationResolver> -->
<util:set id="resolvers" value-type="org.foo.storage.resolvers.LocationResolver">
    <ref bean="memoryLocationResolver"/>
    <ref bean="fsLocationResolver"/>
</util:set>
```

If you want the `Set` bean, I would use `@Resource`

```
@Resource(name = "resolvers")
private Set<LocationResolver> resolvers;
```

Comment: @carlspring Can you post the stack trace of the NPE?

Comment: As per your request, I have pasted the exception here: http://pastebin.com/Psy3q5Bp.

Comment: @carlspring It seems like your `LocationResolver` beans have a back reference to the `ConfigurationManager`. This might cause race issues. Which bean gets initialized first and injected first? These circular dependencies can be an issue. Look into that.

Comment: This is my bet too, for what it's worth.

Comment: How would you guys propose I tackle it?

Comment: @carlspring One way is to simply make it a POJO with no reference to ConfigurationManager. It'd be best if you post the code for FSLocationResolver so we can see what we're dealing with. You can also try lazy initialization.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, mttdbrd: Thanks for your invaluable input! The cyclic dependency was the cause. Thanks for pointing out the other issues as well! :)